# Use thrust to find element in groups

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have two int vectors for keys and values, their size is about 500K.

The key vector is already sorted. And there are 10K groups approximately.

The value is non-negative(stands for useful) or -2(stands for no use), in each group there should be one or zero non-negative values, and the rest is -2.

```
key:   0  0  0  0 1  2  2  3  3  3  3 
value:-2 -2  1 -2 3 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  0
```

The third pair of group 0 `[0 1]` is useful. For group 1 we get the pair`[1 3]`. The values of group 2 are all -2, so we get nothing. And for group 3, the result is `[3  0]`.

So, the question is how can I do this by thrust or cuda ?

Here are two ideas.

**First one**:
Get the number of each group by a histogram algorithm. So the barrier of each group can be computed.
Operate `thrust::find_if` on each group to get the useful element.

**Second one**:
Use `thrust::transform` to add 2 for every value and now all the value are non-negative, and zero stands for useless.
Use `thrust::reduce_by_key` to get the reduction for every group, and then subtract 2 for every output value.

I think there must be some other methods which will achieve much more performance than the above two.

Performance of the methods:

I have test the **Second** method above and the method given by **@Robert Crovella**, ie. **reduce_by_key** and **remove_if** method.
The size of the vectors is 2691028, the vectors consist of 100001 groups. Here is their average time:

```
reduce_by_key: 1204ms
remove_if: 192ms
```

From above result, we can see that remove_if method is much faster. And also the "remove_if" method is easy to implement and consume much less gpu memory.

Briefly, @Robert Crovella 's method is very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `thrust::zip_iterator` to [zip the key and values pairs together](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), and then I would do a [`thrust::remove_if`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html) operation on the zipped values which would require a functor definition that would indicate to remove every pair for which the value is negative (or whatever test you wish.)

Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t1009.cu
#include <thrust/remove.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

struct remove_func
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(T &t){
    return (thrust::get<1>(t) < 0); // could change to other kinds of tests
    }
};

int main(){

  int keys[] = {0,0,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3};
  int vals[] = {-2,-2,1,-2,3,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,0};
  size_t dsize = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(int);

  thrust::device_vector<int>dkeys(keys, keys+dsize);
  thrust::device_vector<int>dvals(vals, vals+dsize);
  auto zr = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dkeys.begin(), dvals.begin()));

  size_t rsize = thrust::remove_if(zr, zr+dsize, remove_func()) - zr;

  thrust::copy_n(dkeys.begin(), rsize, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::copy_n(dvals.begin(), rsize, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o t1009 t1009.cu
$ ./t1009
0,1,3,
1,3,0,
$
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made a mistake in the example data, and now I have revised it. I will test these method and put the code and their performance evaluation later.